# Conditions for "mds cluster is degraded"

Tags: ceph

I see into Ceph and after running command
*$ ceph status*
I meet text "mds cluster is degraded". I try to seek it at [official Ceph docs](http://ceph.com/docs), but nothing find.
If I understand correctly, MDS needed for mounting and presenting ceph's data as regular FS.
Can someone talk about conditions of appearance for this type of error?

Comment: Generically (not ceph-specific), "cluster is degraded" usually means one of your peer-servers is slow to respond, not responding at all, or inconsistent and cannot be synchronized. What do your /var/log/ceph/*mds* logfiles have to say about it?

Comment: Something like `2014-12-18 16:41:17.885417 7f222eb4a700  0 -- 10.0.0.1:6800/1602 >> 10.0.0.254:0/2864344358 pipe(0x1ba7b200 sd=34 :6800 s=2 pgs=2 cs=1 l=0 c=
0x3b8caa0).fault with nothing to send, going to standby`